# AOP. Application produce one GC log and crashes after specifying AspectJ as javaagent

Tags: deployment, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have main application and this application have dependency on custom lib which use AOP. And when I deploy main application I need to specify this -javaagent to make dependency work.

When I specified -javaagent for application I only get one GC log and no additional info.

**Command**:
`java -Dlog4j.logLevel=ALL -javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar -Xlog:gc -Xlog:gc* -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -cp application org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

**LOGS**:

```
[0.018s][info][gc] Using G1
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Version: 17.0.2+8-86 (release)
[0.081s][info][gc,init] CPUs: 16 total, 4 available
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Memory: 10240M
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Large Page Support: Disabled
[0.081s][info][gc,init] NUMA Support: Disabled
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Compressed Oops: Enabled (Zero based)
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Heap Region Size: 4M
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Heap Min Capacity: 8M
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Heap Initial Capacity: 8G
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Heap Max Capacity: 8G
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Pre-touch: Disabled
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Parallel Workers: 4
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Concurrent Workers: 1
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Concurrent Refinement Workers: 4
[0.081s][info][gc,init] Periodic GC: Disabled
[0.081s][info][gc,metaspace] CDS archive(s) mapped at: [0x0000000800000000-0x0000000800bdf000-0x0000000800bdf000), size 12447744, SharedBaseAddress: 0x0000000800000000, ArchiveRelocationMode: 0.
[0.081s][info][gc,metaspace] Compressed class space mapped at: 0x0000000800c00000-0x0000000840c00000, reserved size: 1073741824
[0.081s][info][gc,metaspace] Narrow klass base: 0x0000000800000000, Narrow klass shift: 0, Narrow klass range: 0x100000000
```

**That's basically all. I am very curious why there is no more logs or info about error.**

I use aspectJWeaver as explicit jar in my k8s pod. It works on my machine but I have problems remotely.

I've tried to change path for lib but that doesn't work.

**Some specifics I've removed from run command to not share it**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Can you debug invisible code and incomplete command lines?

Comment: I actually tried your command line arguments on a small Spring Boot application with AspectJ weaver as a java agent, even adding a another java agent to the command line, on JDK 17 (Windows 10). No problems. I see similar logs as you, but no application crash. So like I said, your exact use case or a minimal, complete, anonymised reproducer of it you can publish is necessary.

Comment: Hi, my question have specification in pod usage. I mount aspectJ jar to pod. Do I need to mount also all others files from library to make it work? Like aspectjweaver-1.9.20.pom or _remote.repositories. I thought maybe it is the reason why simple aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar doesn't work

Comment: Locally, on my machine, it works perfectly

Comment: @kriegaex can I embedded aspectJ as javaagent inside my Spring Boot app? To avoid explicit usage of -javaagent:/

Comment: That is an extra question and does not belong to this one here. If that would make your problem go away, it would only indicate that the aspect weaving agent was not the root cause of your problem but something was wrong with your configuration. Sorry, if there is no way to reproduce your problem, I cannot help you and am out of here.

Comment: You did not even explain what kind of "pod" you run your application in, not to mention a reproducer project doing that. If you can reproduce it in a minimal application in a "pod", that would be something to work on. If you think, you cannot share the application, then hire an expert who can sign an NDA before helping you.